# Python OrbitalPy Traceback error Cartesian State Vectors Position and Velocity from Keplerian Elements

Tags: python, vector, cartesian-coordinates, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to get the cartesian position and velocity vectors for each propagation step in my orbit. I am using OrbitalPy http://pythonhosted.org/OrbitalPy/ to generate the orbit with classical Keplerian elements.

According to the documentation I should be able to get the state vectors (both position and velocity) from `class orbital.utilities.StateVector` , but I get a Type Error: **new**() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.constants import kilo

import orbital
from orbital import earth, KeplerianElements, Maneuver, plot, utilities
from orbital.utilities import Position, Velocity

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Orbit Setup
orbitPineapple = KeplerianElements.with_period(96 * 60, body=earth, i=(np.deg2rad(51.6)))
plot(orbitPineapple)
plt.show()
orbitPineapple

Out[23]: KeplerianElements(a=6945033.343911132,
                  e=0,
                  i=0.90058989402907408,
                  raan=0,
                  arg_pe=0,
                  M0=0.0,
                  body=orbital.bodies.earth,
                  ref_epoch=<Time object: scale='utc' format='jyear_str' value=J2000.000>)

prop1 = orbital.maneuver.PropagateAnomalyTo(M=1.00)
orbitX = orbitPineapple.apply_maneuver(prop1)
plot(orbitPineapple, title='Go Pineapple!')
plt.show()

orbital.utilities.StateVector(orbitPineapple)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-91fb5303082b> in <module>()
      4 #print(orbital.utilities.StateVector.velocity(orbitPineapple))
      5 
----> 6 orbital.utilities.StateVector(orbitPineapple)
      7 #orbital.utilities.StateVector.position(orbitPineapple())
      8 
    TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is with OrbitalPy. One can only get state vectors when using the original orbit name.

In this case `orbitPineapple.r` would return position (x,y,z) and `orbitPineapple.v` would return (Vx,Vy,Vy).

The position and velocity vectors are update after each maneuver is applied just use the exact same line with the original orbit name `print(orbitPineapple.r, orbitPineapple.v)`.

Additionally, a super useful feature that would have saved me hours, is you can just type a variable or function and `name.` and hit the ***tab key*** and all the options are displayed.

Comment: The position vector is in a Geocentric Equatorial Inertial (GEI) reference frame which is GCRS in AstroPy for anyone looking to convert coordinates to other systems. `gcrs.transform_to()` is great in AstroPy

Answer (score 2):

I don't use this package but the error is simple enough to diagnose. From [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/OrbitalPy/modules/utilities/#orbital.utilities.StateVector) you can see that `orbital.utilities.StateVector` takes two arguments; one for "position" and one for "velocity". When you do `orbital.utilities.StateVector(orbitPineapple)` you only supply one argument (`orbitPineapple`) whose value will be taken as representing "position". You need to supply velocity too.

As for the error `...takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`, python overestimates the number of required/passed arguments for class methods because it takes the `self` parameter into account when it is counting them up. For example:

```
class Testing(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2

    def do_something(self, b):
        self.a += b

obj = Testing()
obj.do_something(2, 3) # Clearly passing only 2 arguments
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: do_something() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So you can read the error as "takes 2 arguments but you only gave 1"

Comment: I was under the impression that orbital.utilities.StateVector would give me the position and velocity vectors in cartesian coordinates as opposed to me having to input them. I thought the `classmethod from_state_vector(r, v, body, ref_epoch=<Time object: scale='utc' format='jyear_str' value=J2000.000>)` was used to make an orbit from state vectors.

Comment: Is there some way to get the state vectors for my propagated orbit with `orbital.utilities.StateVector` ? With something like `orbitPineapple.orbital.utilities.StateVector` or something along those lines ?

Comment: @rose I'm afraid I don't know anything about this library. My answer explains the error message only. For your first comment, it definitely seems that your assumption is incorrect based on the documentation and the error you got. But I would need to know the context of the problem and be invested in it too to try understand how the library should be used for anything more (it seems a niche library that might take some time to learn).