# Python Spyder error TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, spyder

I get this error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

after this code:

```
ecomm_stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer('ecomm').stem
```

How does this code have 2 arguments?

Comment: @CoryKramer I didn't tag as a dupe and I also got the link wrong. Oops.

Comment: @CoryKramer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350322/4799172) was the answer I intended to link to, but there has to be a better target for this kind of question (`self` being included in the argument count).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python super() with \_\_init\_\_() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the argument in the wrong location

```
ecomm_stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer().stem('ecomm')
```

As the error mentions, `PorterStemmer` has an `__init__` that only takes one argument, which is implicitly `self`. The `'ecomm'` argument should be passed to the stemmer's [`stem`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html) method.

Comment: I don't know what any of your coding vocabulary means .............. ecomm is the dataset? or am I supposed to leave the () blank?                       Its supposed to be part of the following code:       import numpy
from nltk.cluster import KMeansClusterer, GAAClusterer, euclidean_distance
import nltk.corpus
from nltk import decorators
import nltk.stem
from nltk.stem.snowball import EnglishStemmer


ecomm_stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer('ecomm').stem